# Lograthmic yaxsis setting not working in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I have previous experience in plotly , now I am trying similar graphs with Chart.js. In plotly I can set `yaxis_type="log"` , which will automatically scale the values of Y axis. I am tryin gto do a similar thing in chart.js , but unable to achieve desired output.

My chart.js output looks like
[image]

The Y axis starts from 0 and jumps directly to 20000 , so it is quite difficult to visualize the first three lines. I would like it to be scaled accordingly based on the values.

My JS code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: {{xaxis|safe}},
        datasets: {{data_Categoryline|safe}}
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Category wise Trend'
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display : true,
                scaleLabel :{
                    display : true,
                    labelString : 'Across the days/weeks/months'
                }           
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                     type: 'logarithmic'
                },
                scaleLabel :{
                    display : true,
                    labelString : 'Total Amount'
                } 

            }]
        },
        legend: {
            position : 'right'
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis `type` must not be defined inside the `ticks` option but directly on the axis as follows:

```
yAxes: [{
  type: 'logarithmic',
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: false        
  },
```

> Please consult [Cartesian Axes Common Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-configuration) from Chart.js documentation.

Comment: Thanks for yur help. This seems to work , but I am getting values in scientific numbers like '5e+3' , is there any option to display them as numbers or currency ?

Comment: @Ragesh Kr: Yo can define a `yAxes.ticks.callback` function to have your tick labels formatted in the way you wish (see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats)